# Parse XML on Android using inputstream from Cache

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, inputstream

I want to parse a XML file from a server on internet and save it locally for some time so that if the connectivity is lost I can still see the information on app.

I am able to successfully parse the XML file from the internet. I am also able to save it in the cache directory`getCacheDir()`, files directory`getFilesDir()` and external storage.

Now, I want to parse the local XML file and still want to use the same function that I used to parse the XML from internet. However after several tries and hours of searching I am not able to parse the `inputstream` from the file stored in Cache directory or the Files directory. The only directory the function works on is the external directory.

So this code **WORKS**:

```
inputstream is;
File file = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/Fmobile/Cache","Newfile.xml");                   
is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(is);
```

While the following code does **NOT** work.

```
inputstream is;
File file = new File (getFilesDir(),"Newfile.xml");                 
is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(is); **// Error is given on this line : "Is a directory"**
```

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between the above two code or what should be done to get the inputstream from the Cache directory or the Files directory.
Just so you know I have tried replacing the `getFilesDir()` with the path to the file.

Most solutions I have searched for talk about storing the file in asset or res folder but I cannot do that because it is a dynamic file which will keep changing and that's why I need to use cache and timeout.

I am sorry for any mistakes that I might have made while posting this. This is my first post.

The Log Cat is as follows:

```
04-04 11:27:24.579: I/com.example.app1.FMobileActivity(16029): Running Form [2] Local File
04-04 11:27:24.579: I/com.example.app1.FMobileActivity(16029): ProcessForm Data2
04-04 11:27:24.579: I/com.example.app1.FMobileActivity(16029): /data/data/com.example.app1/cache/Newfile2.xml
04-04 11:27:24.589: E/com.example.app1.FMobileActivity(16029): Error occurred in ProcessForm:Is a directory
04-04 11:27:24.589: W/System.err(16029): java.io.IOException: Is a directory
04-04 11:27:24.599: W/System.err(16029):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.read(Native Method)
04-04 11:27:24.599: W/System.err(16029):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:165)
04-04 11:27:24.599: W/System.err(16029):    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:290)
04-04 11:27:24.599: W/System.err(16029):    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:245)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:140)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:225)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.setInput(KXmlParser.java:1044)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:114)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at com.example.app1.FMobileActivity.GetFormData(FMobileActivity.java:315)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at com.example.app1.FMobileActivity.onCreate(FMobileActivity.java:58)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1727)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:647)
04-04 11:27:24.609: W/System.err(16029):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 11:27:24.609: E/com.example.app1.FMobileActivity(16029): Couldn't parse the Form.
04-04 11:27:24.689: D/dalvikvm(16029): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 118K, 48% free 2837K/5379K, external 2743K/2773K, paused 33ms
```

Comment: Are you *certain* the error is on that line rather than on the `FileInputStream` constructor? Please post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following to get a document from a string. String can be obtained by downloading a file or by reading a file locally. SO it solves the problem I had. If anyone needs help in getting the contents of local file as a string let me know in comments. It is fairly simple same fro fetching data from online server.

```
public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml)
{
    if(xml!=null)
    {
    /* Replace the & in string with &amp (if any) */
        String xmlNew=clearRefs(xml);
        Document doc = null;
    //  Log.v(tag,"After Clearing refs::"+xmlNew);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Log.v(tag,"Trying Obtaining Document");
        try {
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlNew));
            doc = db.parse(is); 
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e(tag,"XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            connectionStatus="No data received";
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(tag,"I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
            connectionStatus="No data received";
            return null;
        }
        return doc;
    }
    else
    {
        connectionStatus="Null string Passed";
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whene you are downloading the xml file use this code:

```
try {
            URL   urlxml = new URL(YOUR_XML_FILE_URL);
            URLConnection ucon = urlxml.openConnection();
            ucon.setConnectTimeout(4000);
            ucon.setReadTimeout(4000);
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, 128);
            FileOutputStream fOut =this.openFileOutput("myFile.xml", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            int length = ucon.getContentLength();
            int current = 0;
            long total = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                total += current;
                osw.write((byte) current);
            }
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            finishUpdate = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            finishUpdate = false;
        }
```

And for retreving and parsing the downloaded xml file use :

```
 SAXParserFactory fabrique = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parseur = null;
    ArrayList temp = null;
    try {
        parseur = fabrique.newSAXParser();
        DefaultHandler handler = new ParserXMLHandler();

        File fs=context.getFilesDir();
        File file = new File(fs.getAbsoluteFile(),"Myfile.xml");
        parseur.parse(file, handler);


    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This would have worked if I didn't had the restriction of using same function for both files (One on internet and one stored locally). Also I cannot use SAXParser. I am using javax.xml.parsers. But your answer gave me an idea on a different problem that I had. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The db.parse is taking "file" and returning "document".

Maybe you need to change your code like : db.parse(is) to db.parse(file)

Comment: Nopes it does not work. It still gives the same error: `"Is a directory".`
What baffles me in this problem is that the same function and code works if I try to read from `/mnt/sdcard/Fmobile/Cache` while not from the `/data/data/com.example.app1/cache/` given by `getFilesDir()` or even from `getCacheDir()`.
Now since this works with external storage I think it might have something to do with permission or how android handles internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard,"/Newfile.xml");
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(is);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ended up doing it a little differently but I think it is a better solution than my original approach. I created three functions. 
1) Download file + Extract Content as string (In case of online interaction)

2) Open file saved locally + Extract content as String (In case of offline interaction)

3) Once I have the String parse the String to get a XML document.